# How to add to the export table of a decompiled DLL

Tags: dll

I have decompiled the DLL and I want to add the address of one of the functions to the export table.

Comment: Was the DLL _decompiled_ or _disssembled_? There is a big difference in the type of file(s) generated by these processes. Was a .def file generated? This is important as well. The more information you provide the more complete the answers will be.

Comment: disassembled sorry. I cant find a .def file. I'm using IDA pro but can get other software if it makes it easier.

Comment: Anybody know how to do it?